# Abstracting reference containers (Rc, Arc, Box, ...)

Tags: rust, dependency-injection

I've been hobby programming in Rust for a while now and there's something annoying me when I try to create abstractions. Here's a small example I made of the kind of code I end up with when writing a program in a dependency injection style:

```rust
type UserId = u8;

pub struct User {}

pub struct UserDatabase {}

impl UserDatabase {
    pub fn get(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct UserService {
    user_database: UserDatabase
}

impl UserService {
    fn get_user(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User {
        self.user_database.get(user_id)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let user_database = UserDatabase{};

    let user_service = UserService{
        user_database
    };

    user_service.get_user(todo!());
}
```

In this example the `UserService` exposes a `get_user` method. Internally, this calls a `UserDatabase`. This `UserDatabase` is injected into the `UserService` in the `main` method.

So this all works well, but consider the scenario now that this `UserDatabase` needs to get used (injected into) another service:

```rust
pub struct SomeOtherService {
    user_database: UserDatabase
}

fn main() {
    let user_database = UserDatabase{};

    let user_service = UserService{
        user_database
    };

    let some_other_service = SomeOtherService{
        user_database
    };

    user_service.get_user(todo!());
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't compile as we've tried to move `user_database` twice in `main`.

So we have to wrap it in something like an `Rc`:

```rust
let user_database = Rc::new(UserDatabase{});
```

But this means now, in order to be able to inject it into `user_service`, we have to also wrap the type in the `UserService` struct in an `Rc`:

```rust
pub struct UserService {
    user_database: Rc<UserDatabase>
}
```

This bothers me because:

- Changing the way the `UserService` was used externally, forced us to alter the internal structure of `UserService`.
- `UserService` is now aware of the fact that `UserDatabase` is used elsewhere. The `UserService` only needs the `UserDatabase` to call 1 function. Why should it have to be aware of the fact that the `UserDatabase` is referenced elsewhere? Objectively I know the answer to this: it's because the program has to work out how to safely dereference the value from the heap without interfering with other parts of the code; but as programmers we don't want to leak unnecessary details to the implementation of a function.

Similarly for something like `Arc`, all the parts of the program would now have to be aware they are operating in a multi-threaded scenario.

Is there some way we can achieve a kind of structure where `UserService` is not aware of how the `UserDatabase` type is wrapped? One idea that comes to mind is having a trait:

```rust
trait GetUserDatabase {
    fn get(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User;
}
```

and then somehow being able to make `Rc<UserDatabase>` or `Arc<UserDatabase>` implement that trait.

Perhaps I'm missing some neat tricks here or perhaps I just need alter my traditional Golang/Java mindset when approaching patterns like dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust is not designed for Java's dependency injection mindset, indeed.

> `UserService` is now aware of the fact that `UserDatabase` is used elsewhere. The `UserService` only needs the `UserDatabase` to call 1 function. Why should it have to be aware of the fact that the `UserDatabase` is referenced elsewhere?

Because this is exactly the kind of things Rust wants to be *explicit* about.

This is not just a limitation: Rust wants you to know who owns your objects. The ownership system should design your mind and your program. This "share-style" is indeed not very Rusty - and one of the reasons `Rc` and friends are not commonly seen in idiomatic Rust (they do appear, but not at the same amount as GC'd languages).

Do not think about services - think about data. Instead of asking *who needs access to the user database*, ask *of whom it is*. The owner does not *inject* the DB to whoever needs it, he just let them take a look. If `main()` owns the database, the services should take a reference to it (or not exist at all). If both services own it, it should be `Rc`. Either way, you have to be explicit about that. And that's a good thing!

Answer (score 3):

If you do dependency injection, you should likely base your design on a *trait*. For example:

```
pub trait UserDatabase {
    fn get(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User;
}

// UserService works with any database that implements the trait

pub struct UserService<Db> {
    user_database: Db,
}

impl<Db: UserDatabase> UserService<Db> {
    fn get_user(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User {
        self.user_database.get(user_id)
    }
}
```

The implementation of the trait is no more complex than before:

```
pub struct UserDatabaseImpl {}

impl UserDatabase for UserDatabaseImpl {
    fn get(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

...and your `main()` looks the same, too:

```
fn main() {
    let user_database = UserDatabaseImpl {};
    let user_service = UserService { user_database };
    user_service.get_user(todo!());
}
```

But now, if you want to share the database, you no longer need to modify `UserService` - you only need to provide a new implementation of the trait that allows such sharing. In the above case it can even make use of the non-sharing implementation:

```
impl UserDatabase for Rc<UserDatabaseImpl> {
    fn get(&self, user_id: UserId) -> User {
        self.as_ref().get(user_id)
    }
}
```

The database can now be shared among multiple services without modifying the implementation of `UserService` or `SomeOtherService`:

```
pub struct SomeOtherService<Db> {
    user_database: Db,
}

fn main() {
    let user_database = Rc::new(UserDatabaseImpl {});
    let user_service = UserService {
        user_database: Rc::clone(&user_database),
    };
    let some_other_service = SomeOtherService {
        user_database: Rc::clone(&user_database),
    };
    user_service.get_user(todo!());
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Note that `impl UserDatabase for Borrow<UserDatabaseImpl>` would cover an owned impl, borrowed impl, boxed/rc/arc impl, with a single implementation.

Comment: Though the downside here is the same as the generic approach in my answer: it leaks details about the dependencies of the user service through the generic arguments.

Comment: @cdhowie Whether that's really a downside or "leaking" depends on the usage - you might _want_ to keep these services separate on the type level.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer is correct for your given situation, so you should definitely follow the advice given there and accept it as correct.  This answer is intended to answer the direct question given in the title, for anyone else who happens to land here from a web search and *does* need this functionality.

---

The standard library trait you are looking for here is [`Borrow<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html), which means "you can borrow a `T` from this."

`Borrow<T>` is implemented for the smart pointers `Rc<T>`, `Arc<T>`, `Box<T, _>`, and `Cow<'_, T>`.  `Borrow<T>` is even implemented for `T` and `&T`, so you can handle owned values and references exactly the same way as smart pointers.

---

One way to make use of this trait would be with generics:

```
pub struct UserService<UserDB: Borrow<UserDatabase>> {
    user_database: UserDB
}
```

The caveat to this approach is that `UserService` is now a generic type, so anything else that comes into contact with it needs to be aware (on some level) of the generic type argument.  If you use this approach on every service type in the program, the generics may "infect" the rest of the program to a, quite frankly, obnoxious degree -- anything that used to accept a `UserService` now needs to accept a `UserService<impl Borrow<UserDatabase>>`.  This also leaks details about the dependencies of a service to any facility that uses it, which is likely undesirable.

---

A second approach that doesn't have the downsides of the generic approach is:

```
pub struct UserService {
    user_database: Box<dyn Borrow<UserDatabase>>
}
```

Now if you have a `UserDatabase`, you can give it a `Box<UserDatabase>`.  If you have an `Rc<UserDatabase>` you can give it a `Box<Rc<UserDatabase>>`.  To borrow an existing instance without using a smart pointer, you can give it a `Box<&UserDatabase>`.

However, this approach has its own problems: there is an extra level of indirection, as well as requiring dynamic dispatch to invoke `Borrow::borrow()`.  The performance hit could be worth the added flexibility, but that is a call you would have to make.

Comment: Is this needed? Don't all these pointer types implement all the traits `T` implements because of the `Deref` impl they have?

Comment: @StevenRoose No, [`Deref` doesn't propagate traits](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ead054b200b35525532e922e6da1901f).